# how to update fields of a nested object in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Salam (means Hello) :)

I'm using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver and I need to update specific fields of objects stored in an array. this is a sample document in my mongodb collection:

```
{
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "en" : "birthDate",
            "status" : "enable",
            "index" : 10
        },{
            "en" : "email",
            "status" : "enable",
            "index" : 4
        },{
            "en" : "inviterCode",
            "status" : "enable",
            "index" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my new data:

```
var newData = [ 
    {
        "en" : "birthDate",
        "status" : "disable",
    },{
        "en" : "email",
        "status" : "disable",
    }
];
```

as you can see, if `en` field matches, `status` field should be updated. I know that following query works for a single update, but how can I achieve multiple updates with a single query?

```
collection.update(
    {'fields.en': 'birthDate'}, 
    {$set:{'fields.$.status': 'disable'}}, 
    {w:1, multi: true}, 
    function(error, count){

    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible using a single update. There is a [open ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) over at MongoDB for this.

For now you would need to do this programatically (e.g. looping through the array to find the relevant indexes).